# API cannot connect to SQL with Docker

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-8

I wrote a simple ASP.NET Core 8 Web API. It must connect to SQL Server Express. If I run it with HTTPS it works fine and connects to the database. If I run it with Docker or Docker compose, it works but does not connect to the database.

Here it is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./Euro_WeatherForecast.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Euro_WeatherForecast.dll"]
```

And my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  euro_weatherforecast:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}euroweatherforecast
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Euro_WeatherForecast/Dockerfile
```

This is my connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "AppDbContext": "server=sqlserver;port=8080;Data Source=TUF1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Euronext_WeatherForecast;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False"
```

The container runs in docker, the service SQL Server and SQL Server browser are running. Firewall is deactivated.

Comment: It's unclear from your question but, if the SQL Server are running on the host (!) machine, unless the host is accessible to the container network's DNS, the container will be unable to access the host's service. One solution is to put the container on the host's network using [`network_mode: "host"`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode)

Comment: Port 8080 is probably not correct, especially since you're specifying instance name. Is sql server running inside docker too or outside? Also, what error are you getting exactly? Doesn't connect is same as telling your mechanic that something is wrong with your car

Comment: @DazWilkin . SQL server is not supposed to run on the host, although everything should be in the localhost. When I do it I receive the error during the execution cannot find any host port in the container ....

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very explicit about it but if the SQL server is running on the same machine.

One solution might be to use host.docker.internal as the hostname to refer to the host machine from within a Docker container (https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host)

Giving something like :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "AppDbContext": "server=host.docker.internal;port=8080;Data Source=TUF1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Euronext_WeatherForecast;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False"
}
```

Some other points to consider :

- The port 8080 is quite unusual for SQL Server.
- Last thing the `Integrated Security` property use Windows
  Authentication, but in  a docker container it might not work as
  expected. In this case specifying a username and password directly in
  the connection string could make the deal.

Comment: With "server=host.docker.internal,8080;Data Source=TUF1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Euronext_WeatherForecast;Encrypt=False" I receive the error on swagger:  A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: The SQL runs on the same machine. I ma learning API with docker at home. I access MSSMS with windows authenticaiotion, should I use the same login and pwd of the windows?